# Should I do a task which being told to "Forget About It" 3 days before resigning

Tags: professionalism, management, resignation

I have come across a situation where I am being asked and told to "forget about it [a task]" which do not instruct by anyone that I am responsible to the task. The incident happened 3 days before the last day of my work in that company.

Person involved : my supervisor and me.

Should I do my best to finish that task in 3 days time? or should I really forget about the task?

> **My Concerns**

1. The task is not instruct to me or anyone at first, if I do it, will I be a busy body?
2. If I don't do it, will I being point-out when they miss their "deadline" because of the task?

p/s: This is my first job, and afraid it will affects me in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Well, my boss do not know anything about this...Is this a prank or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "resign" ?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited...@JoeStrazzere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having real trouble understanding your question, so I'm going to speak generally.

If your boss is telling you to forget about it - forget about it.  He's made the decision that this isn't a big deal, and he's accepted any consequences.

If you're working on something with a coworker who says "forget about it", keep track of the task, but let your boss know that you won't be working on it unless he decides otherwise.

In essence - whoever has primary responsibility for meeting a schedule should have some say in how work gets offboarded when an employee leaves a company.  Overall, one technique I've used is that I keep a list of all the tasks I was responsible for, all the equipment I had and any particular professional connections that my boss might want to know about.  As I find a place to transfer all these items, I check them off the list.  I keep my boss aware of the list, giving him updated copies every few days with a final copy before departure.

Comment: yup, thanks for the reply...
I plan to finish the task and upload it at a place which accessible for everyone in my team..
will acknowledge my team lead this incidents.